# Excel having a field day changing the appearance of dates

Tags: excel

I have a mac - sigh. I am using excel on the mac.

All date fields have the type of "date", with a format of month/day/year (eg 3/14/2019)

If I enter the value as 10/13/2019, then all is well.
If I enter the value as 10/12/2019, then excel will *store* it as 10/12/2019, but display it as 12/10/2019

What I mean is that looking at the cells, you'll see 12/10/2019. However, if you click on the cell, then in the little text field at the top, the cell contents are displayed as "10/12/2019".

This is going to confuse the hell out of my american co-workers - it is already confusing me.

I can solve this by putting a ' in front of the 10/12/2019 date... but I'm not sure why Excel is doing its best to make such a mess of this. Is there some way to tell it to stop "auto correcting" things?

Comment: This has to do with your regional settings. The regional settings are dd/mm/yy. Use your regional settings when entering the date and when you American counter parts open it they will see it in their regional settings.  Or you can change your regional settings to match.

Comment: @ScottCraner how do i change the regional settings?

Comment: You can change it by going to Control Panel > Regional Settings (for Windows) or follow this [link](http://osxdaily.com/2012/06/16/change-regional-settings-measurement-units-date-formats-currency-in-mac-os-x/) for mac (sorry, cannot validate if this info is accurate, but looks genuine!). Also consider changing `1904` option in Excel - as per [this](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/change-the-date-system-format-or-two-digit-year-interpretation-aaa2159b-4ae8-4651-8bce-d4707bc9fb9f) Microsoft article, mac and Windows are having different ideas for what is the first system date.

Comment: since neither of you provided an answer, i just found several  answers you both gave in the past and upvoted them